# zf2 dynamic database connection (with parameters)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm trying to create a ZF2 application with multiple databases. Based on a user, the database should be dynamically set.

Right now I've the following:

**database.local.php**

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'adapters' => array (
            'master_db' => array(
                'driver'         => 'Pdo',
                'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=master_db;host=localhost',
                'driver_options' => array(
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
                ),
                'username'       => 'USERNAME',
                'password'       => 'PASSWORD'
            ),
            'tentant_db' => array(
                'driver'         => 'Pdo',
                'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=tenant_db;host=localhost',
                'driver_options' => array(
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
                ),
                'username'       => 'USERNAME',
                'password'       => 'PASSWORD'
            ),
        )
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
                'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory',
        )
    ),
);
```

For test purposes I've created a form that has a method to fetch some data and put it in a select box. The code to get the database connection is shown in the code below.

**MyController.php (in some module)**

```
//... some code
public function someAction(){

        $dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('tentant_db');
        $form = new AddEolConnectorForm($dbAdapter);

        $viewModel = new ViewModel(array(
                                'form' => $form
                            ));
        return $viewModel;


    }

//... some more code
```

My question is, how can I dynamically set the dbname for the tentant_db adapter in my controller (or module)?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/develop/tutorials/config.advanced.html#manipulating-merged-configuration

Comment: @cptnk I don't think I understand what you are trying to say. I'm pretty new to zf2. Can you please give me some more pointers?

Answer (score 0):

The config merge event is one of zend newer event's I believe. It triggers when zend is mergin the config array's which is perfect for the problem you are facing since you can override some array key's dynamically.

```
public function onMergeConfig(ModuleEvent $e)
{
    $configListener = $e->getConfigListener();
    $config         = $configListener->getMergedConfig(false);

    // I'm actually not sure if you have the route match here otherwise you may have to
    // use some other method to retrieve the url.
    $match = $e->getRouteMatch();

    switch ($match) {
    case 'first-dependency':
       $config['db']['adapter'] => array(
          'driver'         => 'Pdo',
          'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=master_db;host=localhost',
          'driver_options' => array(
             PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
          ),
          'username'       => 'USERNAME',
          'password'       => 'PASSWORD',
        ),
    break;

    case 'second-dependency':
       $config['db']['adapter'] => array(
          'driver'         => 'Pdo',
          'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=tenant_db;host=localhost',
          'driver_options' => array(
             PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
          ),
          'username'       => 'USERNAME',
          'password'       => 'PASSWORD',
        ),
    break;

    // Pass the changed configuration back to the listener:
    $configListener->setMergedConfig($config);
}
```

Comment: I think I've found a solution based on your answer. Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above answer I've created to following:

**Module.php**

```
class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface
{
  public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)
    {
        $events = $moduleManager->getEventManager();

        // Registering a listener at default priority, 1, which will trigger
        // after the ConfigListener merges config.
        $events->attach(ModuleEvent::EVENT_MERGE_CONFIG, array($this, 'onMergeConfig'));

    }

    public function onMergeConfig(ModuleEvent $e)
    {

        $db = $this->getTentantDb();
        $configListener = $e->getConfigListener();
        $config         = $configListener->getMergedConfig(false);

        $config['db']['adapters']['tenant_db']['dsn'] = 'mysql:dbname='. $db .';host=localhost';

        $configListener->setMergedConfig($config);
    }

    // Some more code

    public function getTenantDb(){

        $tenant_db = 'tenant_12345'
        return $tenant_db;
    }

}
```

I don't know if it is the best solution, but the above code is working. I think the next steps should be to put the code in a generic module or something so I can access it from all my modules.